# how to let neo4j NSMNTX respect rdf:ID when importing rdf from multiple sources

Tags: neo4j, rdf, semantic-web

I am trying to import multiple rdf files into neo4j as described [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/nsmntx/current/import/)

My problem is that even though elements have the same `rdf:ID` they end up being imported as different neo4j nodes with different uris prefixed by the different file names like `file:/x.xml#_00141f6c-69b1-4a1a-a83b-333d0bb9d586` and `file:/y.xml#_00141f6c-69b1-4a1a-a83b-333d0bb9d586`.

I have tried to use:

```
call semantics.addNamespacePrefix("local","file:/x.xml#")    
call semantics.addNamespacePrefix("local","file:/y.xml#")
```

before importing but to no avail. I have additionally tried to set `handleVocabUris: "MAP"` as an option for the import function.

Is there an import option that I am missing which allows these nodes to be unified? Is there generally an elegant way to reunify them after importing?

Comment: you should raise an issue on their Github project: https://github.com/neo4j-labs/neosemantics/issues

Comment: Good idea: https://github.com/neo4j-labs/neosemantics/issues/140

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to copy each file into a temp file before loading so that the prefixes are the same. Neo4j joins the nodes with the same uri into one, which is exactly what I need.

Still happy to hear about an elegant way to do this though..